# Why RFECV visualizer from yellowbrick finds number of optimal features more than number of features in train set?

Tags: scikit-learn, data-science, feature-selection, yellowbrick

I am trying to perform feature selection and to use RFECV from yellowbrick.model_selection. I have **48 features** in my train set. But when I run the code in below, the visualizer finds **number of features as 49**.

```
xgboost_base_model = xgb.XGBClassifier(tree_method='hist')
visualizer_xgb = RFECV(xgboost_base_model, step=3, cv=3, scoring='roc_auc')
visualizer_xgb.fit(X_train, y_train)
visualizer_xgb.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! I paraphrased and shortened your question. Let me also ask you to output the x_train.head() - maybe there is some extra columns like int index in the input file?

Comment: I checked the shape of X_train and it is (20000,48). There is not any extra columns.

Comment: Could you try to create https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example with a tiny dataset that you can share (so the sensitive info replaced)